# Power Automate: put if condition in column of "Add a row into a table" Object

Tags: power-automate

[image: ![enter image description here]

I'm completely new to POWER AUTOMATE and trying to use an "IF" statement in on output column.
Any advice?

**Update:**
I've modified the IF statement to be an Excel formula - and it worked, not quite as expected though.  The formula uses the literal value of the "Subject" and that is what is used in the cell populated.
Example:

=IF(0<IFERROR(FIND("DocDistro",***Subject literal***),0),"True","")

Anybody know if there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to switch over to the "Expression" tab (this is where you will do any kind of function like this):

[image]

Then start typing "If(contains())", then switch over to the "Dynamic content tab":
[image]

Then you can select the "Subject" item here and it will fill in text inside the formula. If your email action is the trigger than that text will look something like this: "triggerOutputs()?['body/Subject']".

Now add the next paramter to the contains function with a comma followed by the text you are searching for "DocDistro". Your formula bar should now say something like this: "If(contains(triggerOutputs()?['body/Subject'], 'DocDistro'))".

Now fill out the rest of the If fuction by adding ", true, false". When you're done the formula bar should say this: "If(contains(triggerOutputs()?['body/Subject'], 'DocDistro'), true, false)".

Now click the "OK" button:

[image]

Now your excel action will have this pink formula inside the field:

[image]

Comment: Here is some documentation for If functions: https://manueltgomes.com/reference/powerautomate-function-reference/power-automate-if-function/

Comment: Here is some documentation for Contains functions: https://manueltgomes.com/reference/powerautomate-function-reference/contains-function/

Comment: Thank you Sarah, I didn't see your answer till after entering the update - I appreciate your guidance!